# Android getWritableDatabase() throw NullPointerException

Tags: android, database, nullpointerexception

I am trying to save data with database on android.

I have wrote class that handle the database, like I saw in several examples.

```java
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    private Table users;

    public MyDatabase(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        users.CreateTable();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {

    }
}
```

But when I try to initialize the variable `users`, like that:

```java
users = new Table(getWritableDatabase());
```

I get `NullPointerException`, and its not meter where... I tryied:

```java
    public MyDatabase(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        users = new Table(getWritableDatabase());
    }
```

And

```java
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        users = new Table(getWritableDatabase());
        users.CreateTable();
    }
```

But i still get `NullPointerException` when I call to the function `getWritableDatabase()`.
I must that the function `CreateTable` will be not static, because it puts the initial values.

Where I was wrong?

Comment: A class I have been wrote, contains operations on my database table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    users = new Table(getWritableDatabase());
    users.CreateTable();
}
```

by

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    users = new Table(db);
    users.CreateTable();
}
```

When you're in onCreate, your writable database is in the process of getting created.
The onCreate method here is not the same as that in your activity. onCreate for SQLiteOpenHelper is called just the first time the DB is created.

Comment: Ok, so how I will initialize the variable when the database is not new?